# Why do negotiations have to be done at a capital city?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine

[Putin](https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/02/25/putin-ukraine-war-zelensky-talks-minsk/) proposes talks in Minsk.
[Zelenskyy](https://apa.az/en/europe/zelenskyy-we-are-ready-for-talks-with-russia-in-baku-warsaw-budapest-and-istanbul-369532/) is ready for talks with Russia in Baku, Warsaw, Budapest and Istanbul.

I see only capitals here and wonder - does it have to be a capital of some country?

Time seems to be of the essence, the faster the negotiations the fewer casualties the war will have. Why don’t they just take the closest big city, which is easiest to reach? Or not even a city, just a place in an open field - I believe this is how negotiations were done 10 centuries ago, why is it different now?
Another, even more modern and faster option (thanks to @Trilarion) would be a video call.

Comment: Istanbul is not a capital.

Comment: @convert It is, however, an *ex*-capital, back when it was Constantinople.  But you can't go back there...

Answer (score 45):

It doesn't.  Notable locations for summit meetings and treaty negotiations include Yalta, New York, Geneva, and San Francisco, none of which is a national capital (Geneva is the capital city of the Canton of Geneva).

Capital cities can typically provide good security for visiting dignitaries, however, since they're used to protecting their own government officials, as well as the necessary infrastructure.

Comment: I thought of Yalta as well, but a significant difference is that the Yalta Conference was between allies - not warring parties. In any case, I'd add access to a large airport and to friendly embassies to the list of factors that make capitals more suitable for these meetings.

Comment: @yannis that's true.

Comment: Re OPs examples: Istanbul is not a capital. (Might be worth including in the answer.)

Comment: Also note that capitals are usually also where the respective embassies are, which can give each delegation a trusted environment to retreat to for private discussions and communication with the home government.

Comment: Another very notable example: at least some of the final negotiations for the armistices that marked the end (or, at least, the start of the end) of the first and second world wars, took place in a train carriage in a siding in a forest, nowhere near a national capital.

Comment: Its also worth noting that capital cities of other countries are considered the highest of sovereign ground. Should either side decide that whilst they've got the highest member of their enemies government in the same room, they might try to kidnap/knock them off. Doing this in another nations capital will certainly result in diplomatic problems.

Comment: Don't forget [Dayton, OH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayton_Agreement), which isn't even the capital of its state, or [Camp David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_David_Accords), which isn't even a city.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Also [Wye Plantation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wye_River_Memorandum), [Sharm El Sheikh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharm_El_Sheikh_Memorandum), [Taba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taba_Summit), [Annapolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annapolis_Conference), and that's just some of the Israeli–Palestinian talks...

Answer (score 20):

The nearest open field was the choice when emissaries arrived on horseback. Today, a few hundred miles more of distance are less than one hour of flight time.

The choice of the site sets the tone for the negotiations. Hence Russia proposed Minsk, for most practical purposes a Russian client state, while Ukraine named Warsaw, Bratislava, Istanbul, Budapest, and Baku -- all but the latter the capitals of NATO members. Ukraine might win diplomatic points by naming one country that is *slightly* more removed from the conflict.

Comment: do you mean that those are just closest cities with an airport (within corresponding countries)?

Comment: @klm123, what I mean is that in the 21st century, a few more hours of flight time *do not matter* in the decisionmaking. A place that is a longer distance to fly, but easier to agree, leads to a faster meeting.

Comment: "Ukraine might win diplomatic points..." If diplomatic points somewhat resemble rep here, then one cannot buy much from them. But I agree, it seems the notion here is simply that appearance is important in politics.

Comment: There's a big difference between a client state and an allied state.  And given Belarus's [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryanair_Flight_4978) I doubt that any western leaders would feel safe at a summit in Minsk.

Comment: "Ukraine named Warsaw, Bratislava, Istanbul, Budapest, and Baku -- all but the latter the capitals of NATO members": Istanbul is not the capital of Turkey, that's Ankara.

Comment: Why not a video call?

Comment: @akostadinov: I would be fine with that, but the previous generation not so much.

Comment: "Ukraine might win diplomatic points by naming one country that is slightly more removed from the conflict." None of the countries named by Ukraine any any way close to be as involved in the war as Belarus is.

Comment: @akostadinov Security, it's *much* easier to ensure a physical meeting isn't bugged, and security services have much more experience securing and organizing those, than take the risk of an unknown actor (or participant) registering and/or tampering with the video call.

Comment: A meeting between warring parties won't have as much confidential information discussed, and a physical meeting between warring parties can lead to those parties being tracked and made targets after they arrive back home (in Ukraine's case). It's far easier to secure a video call, given the residence itself is already under security.

Comment: @akostadinov Symbolism. A physical meeting requires a higher level of trust, which, even if minimal, can serve as foundation for negotiations.